# figure out whether python module is installed or in develop mode programmatically

Tags: python, packaging

I tend to develop my apps in 'setup.py develop' -mode. I'd want the configuration to switch automagically on production mode when the program gets 'setup.py install'ed.

This can be done by poor hacks, like checking whether installation directory contains 'setup.py', but I wonder whether pkg_resources can do this for me somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, [`pkg_resources` will do that](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#distribution-attributes):

```
dist = pkg_resources.get_distribution('your-app')
if dist.precedence == pkg_resources.DEVELOP_DIST:
    # package is in development mode
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it easier, and cleaner, to just set an environment variable on your development machine, and test for `os.environ['development_mode']` (or a setting of your choice)?

Comment: Perhaps. Though it seems it wasn't neither tricky to get this info through pkg_resources.

Comment: No, but it's still generally a bad idea to base behavior on the manner of installation.  If you want to debug a particular piece of code which only runs outside of development mode, you have to edit the code or reinstall the package.  With the environment setting, you just set the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). Then your development environment could be identical to your production environment. Setuptools is a pretty heavy thing to depend on, in my opinion.